# What three positive integers, upon being multiplied by 3, 5, and 7 respectively and the products divided by 20...

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

What three positive integers, upon being multiplied by 3, 5, and 7 respectively and the products divided by 20, have remainders in arithmetic progression with common difference 1 and quotients equal to remainders?

Comment: Try to put the task into a formula...
$$3a = 20 q_a + r_a$$
$$5b = 20 q_b + r_b$$
$$7c = 20 q_c + r_c$$
etc. What are the exact requirements on $q_a, q_b, q_c$ and $r_a, r_b, r_c$ ?

Comment: It would be much better if you provided your own thoughts on the subject.

Answer (score 1):

$$ 3p =  20c + c = 21c $$
$$ 5q = 20(c + 1) + c+1 = 21 (c+1)$$
$$ 7r = 20(c + 2) + c+2 = 21 ( c+2 )$$

This implies ratio is

$$ 3p : 5q : 7r :: c : c+1 : c+2 $$

so $3p, 5q , 7r$ 's reminders should be consecutive numbers and the reminders equal to quotient 
This condition is satisfied for c = 4

$$84 , 105 ,126 $$

so

$$p = 28$$

$$q = 21$$

$$r = 18$$

Numbers are $28 , 21 ,18$

Comment: Did you just guess and check to find 54, 55, 56?

Comment: By the idea that it has to be around 10's or 5's as 5q is there .

Comment: Actually, I just figured out the correct answer. Let 3a=20x+x, 5b=20(x+1)+(x+1) and 7c=20(x+2)+(x+2). Simplifying, a=7x, b=(21/5)x+(21/5) and c=3x+6. Let x=4. Then a=28, b=21, c=18. This is necessary for the quotients to equal the remainder

Comment: Ya I forgot that condition .Ya u r right .